# Micro:Bit Button Press Delay

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit

I am trying to make a simple game similar to snake (however the player does not get longer over time). The game is almost complete, however I have encountered a problem where the button presses that would normally change the direction that you are moving in are delayed. This makes the game a lot harder than it needs to be.

Basically I need to know how to make the player change direction instantly after a button press, without any delay.

Code:

```
from microbit import *
import random

class Game:

    running = True

    score = 0

    speed = 500

    x = 2
    y = 2

    goalX = random.randint(0, 4)
    goalY = random.randint(0, 4)

    direction = None

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def startGame(self):
        Game.defaultDirection(self)
        display.clear()
        display.set_pixel(self.x, self.y, 9)
        display.set_pixel(self.goalX, self.goalY, 5)
        Game.mainLoop(self)

    def mainLoop(self):
        while self.running is True:
            display.clear()
            Game.checkBorderCollision(self)
            Game.checkGoalCollision(self)
            display.set_pixel(self.x, self.y, 9)
            display.set_pixel(self.goalX, self.goalY, 5)
            Game.buttonAInput(self)
            Game.buttonBInput(self)
            Game.movePlayer(self)

    def defaultDirection(self):
        if self.x == 1:
            self.direction = 0
        if self.x == 3:
            self.direction = 2
        else:
            randomDirection = random.randint(0, 1)
            if randomDirection == 0:
                self.direction = 2
            else:
                self.direction = 0

    def movePlayer(self):
        if self.direction == 2:
            self.x -= 1
            sleep(self.speed)
        if self.direction == 0:
            self.x += 1
            sleep(self.speed)
        if self.direction == 1:
            self.y -= 1
            sleep(self.speed)
        if self.direction == 3:
            self.y += 1
            sleep(self.speed)

    def buttonAInput(self):
        if button_a.was_pressed() or button_a.is_pressed():

            if self.direction == 3:
                self.direction = 0
            else:
                self.direction += 1

    def buttonBInput(self):
        if button_b.was_pressed() or button_b.is_pressed():
            if self.direction == 0:
                self.direction = 3
            else:
                self.direction -= 1

    def checkBorderCollision(self):
        if self.x < 0 or self.x > 4 or self.y < 0 or self.y > 4:
            animation = 0
            if self.direction == 0:
                self.x -= 1
            if self.direction == 2:
                self.x += 1
            if self.direction == 3:
                self.y -= 1
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.y += 1
            while animation < 3:
                display.clear()
                display.set_pixel(self.x, self.y, 9)
                sleep(300)
                display.clear()
                sleep(300)
                animation += 1
            display.scroll(self.score)
            self.score = 0
            self.x = random.randint(1, 3)
            self.y = random.randint(1, 3)
            Game.defaultDirection(self)

    def checkGoalCollision(self):
        if self.x == self.goalX and self.y == self.goalY:
            self.score += 1
            self.goalX = random.randint(0, 4)
            self.goalY = random.randint(0, 4)
            if self.speed == 150:
                pass
            else:
                self.speed -= 10

game = Game()
game.startGame()
```

Comment: When you call a method you don't use `self` only when defining it. But neither should you be using `Game` that should be `self` so the first line of startGame should read `self.defaultDirection()`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line `if self.speed == 150:` to `if self.speed <= 150` . Where do you initialise `self.speed` there should be a line in `.startGame` that sets it to some high value

Comment: `speed` is already defined on line 10. Also, changing that line of code would not get rid of the button delay. The `speed` variable is the speed of the player and does have anything to do with the button presses.